How can one trigger the "Open with WhatsApp" phone action immediately after an Ajax event?
In phones...
onclick="location.href='https://wa.me/[number]'" immediately opened the "Open with WhatsApp" question panel.
location.href = 'https://wa.me/[number]' after an Ajax does not.
Is there a way to work around it?

Are you using any libraries in particular to handle the Ajax? Maybe you can share a bit more code?

You can create a link with the URL using JavaScript and then click it internally.
const newLink = document.createElement("a");
newLink.setAttribute("href", "<yourWhatsAppLink>");
newLink.click();

Replace the <yourWhatsAppLink> with the actual link.
Note: you don't actually need to insert the new link anywhere in the DOM.
